# Webpack babel-loader es2015 presets setting is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack.config.js

When I build react project with webpack, I got an 'Unexpected token' error

**webpack --progress**

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:13)

  11 |     }
  12 | 
> 13 |     onSearch = (e) => {
     |              ^
  14 |         console.log('click');
  15 |     }
```

I thought my project doesn't transpile es6 codes to es5 because wrong setting of `webpack.config.js`, but I can't find what's wrong.

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + "/src/App.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                cacheDirectory: true,
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: First, refrain from using `preset es2015`; instead, use `preset-env`.
Second, if you want to continue with your implementataion, have a look at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-arrow-functions

arrow functions plugin.

Comment: Thanks @GautamBhutani but I download `babel-preset-env` and edit presets to ['env', 'react']`, still has error ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `babel-preset-stage-2` package and try this:

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
...
presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
...
```

In the future, we might not use the *babel's state presets* as this [Removing Babel's Stage Presets](https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/07/27/removing-babels-stage-presets) article said.

However, for now, *it worked really well*

What's Babel's Stage Presets:

> A Babel preset is a shareable list of plugins.
>
> The official Babel Stage presets tracked the TC39 Staging process for
>   new syntax proposals in JavaScript.
>
> Each preset (ex. stage-3, stage-2, etc.) included all the plugins for
>   that particular stage and the ones above it. For example, stage-2
>   included stage-3, and so on.

Comment: Ah stage ! What about 'env' presets? `npm install babel-preset-env`